# can we store ng-bind values to php string

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

First,I am very new to angularjs.I have some knowledge of PHP.
I was wondering if we can store can store ng-bind values to php string.
Lets say:

```js
<li ng-if="jSEO.resources[3][0][0]"> <span> Internal Links:</span> <font color="#000000" size="+2"  ng-bind=" jSEO.resources[3][0][0]"></font>  </li>
```

Can we take the ng-bind value on a php string and then we can insert it to db.
I tried doing this trick but failed.
Any suggestions/code hints are highly appreciated

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, Angular runs on the client. You can add any PHP output to anywhere in your Angular or any other browser-interpreted code.

Comment: @RidIculous  Thanks for the info.i would like to do somthing like this to the code:
<li ng-if="jSEO.resources[3][0][0]"> <span> Internal Links:</span> <font color="#000000" size="+2" <?php $j=''; $j="ng-bind='jSEO.links.length'";?> <?php echo $j;?>
></font>  </li>

and the ng-bind value gets stored in $j for me to insert in mysql.
Is it Possible?Or am I missing something.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you try to achieve. JS/Angular is event-driven and happens on your page whereas anything PHP will have already happened when you load the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this.

1. Create a PHP API and write some javascript to post the value to the API. Have a look at the angular [$httpProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
2. Create a hidden input in a form and set the value of the input to the angular value. That does defeat the purpose of using Angular though.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="myAwsomeValue" value="{{jSEO.resources[3][0][0]}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you .This is exactly what I was looking for.Awesome!